# django cerlery second task not executed

Tags: django, celery, scheduled-tasks

I created a celery `shared_task` which executes another `shared_task`:

```
@shared_task(base=WorkerBase,
             name='analytics.worker-tenant',
             rate_limit='3/m')
def worker_tenant():
    tenants = Tenant.objects.values_list('id', 'contexttenant')

    print('first:worker_tenant')
    for tenant in tenants:
        worker_update_tenant.delay(tenant[0], tenant[1])


@shared_task(name='analytics.worker-update-tenant',
             autoretry_for=(HTTPError, ConnectionError),
             retry_backoff=True)
def worker_update_tenant(id, context, timespan=timedelta(weeks=1)):
    print('worker_update_tenant')
```

I get the output of the first print `first:worker_tenant` but not the second one `worker_update_tenant`.

I have also tried to call the second task with `apply_async(args=(...))` but that also didn't work!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work by using a generator with group instead:

```
group(
    worker_update_tenant.s(tenant[0], tenant[1]) for tenant in tenants
).apply_async()
```